# How to make this list stay at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

Want this to be at the bottom of my page. No blank space beneath it. I'm a little confused as the normal CSS to make text stay at the bottom wont work here.

```css
    .footer li{
      display:inline;
    }
```

```html
    <footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <ul style="float:left;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Advertising</li>
          <li>Business</li>
          <li>About</li>
       </ul>
    
       <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Privacy</li>
          <li>Terms</li>
          <li>Settings</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: You want it to always  be at the bottom of the window (as you scroll, it stays fixed), or just always at the bottom of the page, so if the page is tall, you still have to scroll down to see it?

Comment: Just at the bottom, does not have to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Fix the footer using `position: fixed;` and set `bottom: 0px;` to fix it to the bottom of the page.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width:90%;
}

.footer li{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
 
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <ul style="float:left; list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Advertising</li>
          <li>Business</li>
          <li>About</li>
       </ul>
    
       <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Privacy</li>
          <li>Terms</li>
          <li>Settings</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: This works when I run it on here. But when I changed my source code they're both on the left now. It's not floating right.

Comment: @JacobMoore Fixed. Should've set the width. I've also changed `display: block;`

Comment: I had to change block back to inline, but it worked. Thank you. I understand how this works now, just confused on block, inline, inline-block...

Comment: @JacobMoore I thought you wanted inline removed! Nevertheless, glad to know it helped.

Comment: I'm recreating the Google homepage as a project for the "Odin Project". These lists are the text on the bottom of the page. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a "sticky" footer, since you don't want it fixed to the bottom of the viewport all of the time and just want it to always be at the bottom of the page.

The easiest/modern way to do this is to use a `flex` container and set the `footer` to `margin-top: auto` so it will push itself to the bottom of the container. Set the container to `min-height: 100vh;` and the `footer` will always be at the bottom of the page.

```css
.footer li{
  display:inline;
}
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 0;
min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>nav</nav>
<main>main</main>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <ul style="float:left;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Advertising</li>
          <li>Business</li>
          <li>About</li>
       </ul>
    
       <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Privacy</li>
          <li>Terms</li>
          <li>Settings</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Another way to do it is to assign a `height` to `footer`, and absolutely position it at the bottom of the window, and add `padding` to `body` that matches the height of the `footer`

```css
.footer li{
  display:inline;
}
body {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-bottom: 50px;
margin: 0;
min-height: 100vh;
position: relative;
}
footer {
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; left; 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>nav</nav>
<main>main</main>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <ul style="float:left;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Advertising</li>
          <li>Business</li>
          <li>About</li>
       </ul>
    
       <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
          <li>Privacy</li>
          <li>Terms</li>
          <li>Settings</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```